# colelctionview not calling didDeselectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionView that is pulling data ( and loading into an array) from Firebase. Based on what is selected in my collectionview, I change the color of the selected item. I notice that everytime i select the cell, it correctly prints "Cell Selected". But now when I select another cell, then I never even get into the didDeselectItemAtIndexPath function. Its like that function is never called. What am I doing wrong ? ( I am using Swift 2.3)

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! recCatCell

        cell.selected = true
        print ("Cell Selected")


    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? recCatCell {
                print ("Not Selected: \(cell.recCatLabel.text)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: If the cell is not in the screen, `cellForItemAtIndexPath` will return `nil`. Could you add a log before that `if let` test: `print("Deselect: \(indexPath)")`?

Comment: I fixed this, thanks. Question on this though - If i scroll really quick and then select a different label ( and the previously selected cell is not on screen), then how would I access that cell contents ( so I can change the label color etc for that deselected cell)?

Comment: You can manage that with your dataSource management, in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. For instance, if you have an array of dictionary, you can add a key/value "isSelected", and do it according, and change it when select/deselect is done. Maybe a better solution would be in `recCatCell`  code, to override `setSelected:`